# spring data jpa @OneToMany child id not updating

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring data & boot 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT with MySQL I have a parent & child relationship:

parent:

```
@Entity
public class CustomerSearchResults {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   public Long customerSearchResultsId;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerSearchResults", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   private List<CustomerResult> customerAAAAList;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerSearchResults", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   private List<CustomerResult> customerBBBBList;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerSearchResults", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   private List<CustomerResult> customerCCCCList;
    ....
 }
```

child:

```
@Entity
public class CustomerResult {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerSearchResultsId", nullable = false)
    private CustomerSearchResults customerSearchResults;
       ....
}
```

The parent can have multiple lists of the same child type.  I do not have any foreign keys defined in this or any other of my successful @ManyToOne examples.

I create the results like this:

```
CustomerSearchResults customerSearchResults = new CustomerSearchResults();
customerSearchResults.setCustomerAAAAList(anArrayList);
customerSearchResults.setCustomerBBBBList(anArrayList);
customerSearchResults.setCustomerCCCCCList(anArrayList);
customerResultsRepository.save(customerSearchResults);
```

No errors are thrown and I get the CustomerSearchResults inserted into that table, and the correct CustomerResult records are inserted into that table.  The only problem is the CustomerResults.customerSearchResultsId is null, despite it being declared as not null

Here is how I create the tables via liquibase:

```
 <createTable tableName="CustomerSearchResults">
     <column name="customerSearchResultsId" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
           <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
     </column>
    ...
  </createTable>

 <createTable tableName="CustomerResult">
     <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
          <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
      </column>
      ...
      <column name="customerSearchResultsId" type="bigint"/>
  </createTable>
```

Why would the ref id customerSearchResultsId in the child field not be populated like this?

Answer (score 3):

`nullable = false`
is only used for schema generation, it doesn't do anything while inserting data. You need to set the property on both ends of the relationship, so each entry in your 'anArrayList' must set the customerSearchResults you just created.

Comment: I added code on the setter of my parent class to iterate thru the list of children being added, and manually set the customerSearchResults with "this".   When inspecting the records in the database, I see the proper CustomerSearchResults.customerSearchResultsId in the CustomerResults. customerSearchResultsId field.  This appears to solve the problem, but is that correct or am I building up a huge dependency tree or some other side effect?

Comment: Another way to solve it is adding the array one-by-one instead of the whole array at once. Then you could use a method lilke:
    public void addCustomerAAAResult(CustomerResult customerResult) {
        customerAAAAList.add(customerResult);
        customerResult.setCustomerSearchResults(this);
    }